# How to draw a circle in Java using Canvas

Tags: java, canvas

I have to build a pinball style game using java and canvas for Coursework, however I cannot manage to even draw the circle, I get the following error:
"non-static method fillCircle(int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context"
This is the code I currently have, the locations and diameter classes are otherwise set up and work perfectly:

```
public void drawPinball1()
{
    Canvas.fillCircle(currentXLocation, currentYLocation, getDiameter());
}
```

Comment: This simply means that you can't call the method `fillCircle` as a static method. You need an instance. You'll need to start with a Java 2D tutorial, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/ Or even a basic Java tutorial to understand the message.

Answer (score 4):

**Graphics Class' Drawing Methods**

```
// Drawing (or printing) texts on the graphics screen:
drawString(String str, int xBaselineLeft, int yBaselineLeft);

// Drawing lines:
drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
drawPolyline(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int numPoint);

// Drawing primitive shapes:
drawRect(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height);
drawOval(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height);
drawArc(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle);
draw3DRect(int xTopLeft, int, yTopLeft, int width, int height, boolean raised);
drawRoundRect(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height, int arcWidth, int arcHeight)
drawPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int numPoint);

// Filling primitive shapes:
fillRect(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height);
fillOval(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height);
fillArc(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle);
fill3DRect(int xTopLeft, int, yTopLeft, int width, int height, boolean raised);
fillRoundRect(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height, int arcWidth, int arcHeight)
fillPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int numPoint);

// Drawing (or Displaying) images:
drawImage(Image img, int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, ImageObserver obs);  // draw image with its size
drawImage(Image img, int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height, ImageObserver o);  // resize image on screen
```

In your case you will use `drawOval(int xTopLeft, int yTopLeft, int width, int height);`

[this](http://www.java-examples.com/draw-oval-circle-applet-window-example)  tutorial will may help you.

Reference : https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4b_CustomGraphics.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a object of Canvas and then use it.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    gc.fillOval(10, 60, 30, 30);
    gc.strokeOval(60, 60, 30, 30);
```